# problem with drawing angle sign

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this pic:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Write this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]

  % First, define nodes
\node[inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]left:{$C$}}] (C) at (0, 0) {};  
\node[inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]right:{$D$}}] (D) at (5, 0) {};  
\node[inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]left:{$B$}}] (B) at (2.5, 4) {};  

  % Draw curved path
\draw [line width=2pt, -] (C) -- (D) -- (B) -- (C);
\draw [line width=2pt, ->] (C) -- ($(C)!1.3!(B)$);

  \pic[inner sep=2pt, right, "$\ang{50}$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=.5cm]
    {angle=D--C--B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I complete that?

Angle C is not equal to 50 degree. How can draw angles consistent with reality?

Comment: Please don't post examples which rely on fonts not everyone has unless they are essential to the problem you want help with. Also, please remove packages not required by the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polar coordinates to place `B` and `D`, which allows you to specify the point as `(<angle>:<distance>)`. This ensures the angle is `<angle>`. I would also draw the triangle as a closed path rather than using an open one. This will make the join at the end of the path seamless and is simply a matter of using `-- cycle` in place of the final `-- (C)`. To avoid drawing over a path twice, an `edge` may be used from `B` to create the arrow.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [line cap=round,
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 0.2 with {%
        \draw [line width=1pt] (-1pt,4pt) -- (-1pt,-4pt) (1pt,4pt) -- (1pt,-4pt);
      },
      mark=at position 0.4 with {%
        \draw [line width=1pt] (-1pt,4pt) -- (-1pt,-4pt) (1pt,4pt) -- (1pt,-4pt);
      },
    },
  ]
  \path [draw, line width=2pt,postaction=decorate] (0,0) coordinate [label={[inner sep=5pt]left:{$C$}}] (C) -- ++(50:5) coordinate [label={[inner sep=5pt]left:{$B$}}] (B) edge [->]  coordinate (E) ($(C)!1.3!(B)$) -- ++(-50:5) coordinate [label={[inner sep=5pt]right:{$D$}}] (D) -- cycle;
  \pic[inner sep=2pt, right, "$\ang{50}$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=.5cm]
    {angle=D--C--B};
  \pic[inner sep=2pt, right, "$Z$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=.5cm]
    {angle=D--B--E};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: triangle drawn using two points specified with polar coordinates, a closed path and an edge]

Answer (score 2):

With the package `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,0){D}
    \tkzDefTriangle[two angles = 50 and 50](C,D)
    \tkzGetPoint{B}
    \tkzDrawPoints(C,D,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints(C,D)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(C,D,B)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||,size=6pt](C,B D,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle(D,C,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.4](D,C,B){$50^\circ$}
    \tkzDefBarycentricPoint(C=1,B=-4)
    \tkzGetPoint{Bp}
    \tkzMarkAngle(D,B,Bp)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.4](D,B,Bp){$Z$}
    %\tkzDrawPoint(Bp)
    \draw[->](C)--(Bp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]